# Program to display total of numbers created in a file python

Tags: python

I have written the code below to display the following:

- A number of random integers to be chosen by the user
- The total of these integers
- The total number of numbers

The problem lies in the display of the total, it is concatenating the integers, even though I believe I have used int() correctly.

```
# This program will write a series of random numbers to a file, and then read and print these numbers
# total of all numbers will be displayed
# number of files read from the file will be displayed
import random

def randomNumberMaker():
    random_numbers = open('randoms.txt', 'w')
    try:
        for i in range(int(input('How many random numbers? :'))):
            line_1 = str(random.randint(1, 501))
            random_numbers.write(line_1)
            print(line_1)
    except bad_number:
        print("A non integer was entered, sorry.")
    random_numbers.close()

randomNumberMaker()

random_number_file = open("randoms.txt", "r")

total= 0
number_of_numbers= 0
line = random_number_file.readline()

while line != "" :
    number_of_numbers += 1
    number= int (line)
    total += number
    print(number)
    line = random_number_file.readline()
print ("\nThe total number of numbers:" + str(total) +\
        "\n There are " + str(number_of_numbers)+ \
        " numbers in the file")
```

Comment: Please add an example of the expected output for the "display of the total", so that a potential answer can address a specific problem.

Comment: You may want to add a newline when you write to the file, like 'random_numbers.write(line_1 + '\n')

Answer (score 1):

Just add endline at the end of each random number.

```
line_1 = str(random.randint(1, 501)) + '\n'
```

Since you didn't add any endline character, your input file contains only 1 line of input, and what your code really does is to convert that 1 concatenated string into an int and prints it out.

Answer (score 0):

You used `int()` correctly, but the problem is in your `randoms.txt` file. You write all your numbers in a single line without any spaces, so there is no way for the program to know, where to split your numbers. Adding a line break after you write each number fixes the problem:

```
random_numbers.write(line_1 + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your randomNumberMaker() function. You are writing all numbers in one line and thus always getting back only one number, which is a textual concatenation of all random numbers.

Change the line
`random_numbers.write(line_1)`to `random_numbers.write(line_1+"\n")`and everything will work as expected.